# Чем пропарсить формат fb2 на C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser, fb2

У меня есть много книг в формате **fb2** и мне нужно для каждой книги узнать примерное количество страниц. Так как **fb2** основан на обычном **xml** была идея пропарсить его при помощи **XDocument** и вытянуть оттуда значение body(где находится сам текст).

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("book/Oper/va.fb2");  
 var body = doc.Root.XPathSelectElements("./FictionBook/body/").ToList();
```

Но оно не работает. Вылетает System.Xml.XPath.XPathException. Есть идеи чем еще можно пропарсить формат **fb2**?

Comment: А почему бы просто не исправить ошибку вместо того, чтобы отказываться от метода и искать другой?

Comment: @VladD Ну я как понял ошибка вылетает из-за того, что метод XPathSelectElements не находит нужный мне элемент. Скорее всего XDocument не может нормально пропарсить формат fb2.

Comment: Если исключение не вылетело при загрузке книги, значит это корректный xml.

Comment: Вы не сможете узнать "примерное количество страниц". Потому что там нет таких данных. Там просто текст. А вот как он будет отрисован - зависит от конкретной читалки. Может она по слову на страницу будет рисовать.

Comment: @KoVadim Одна условно-стандартная страница в большинстве случаев включает 1800 печатных знаков  (по крайней мере у переводчиков так принято)

Comment: разве что только в условных страницах.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вот первых у вас невалидный XPath - в нем лишний слеш на конце.

Во вторых, `FictionBook` - это и есть Root, нет смысла выбирать его из него же самого.

В третьих, элемента `body` в fb2 нет. Есть элемент `body` с неймспейсом `"http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0"` - а это с точки зрения XML совсем не то же самое, что элемент без неймспейса.

Поэтому для выборки элемента через XPath вам понадобится как создать `XmlNamespaceManager`, зарегистрировать в нем префикс для нейспейса и потом уже выбирать ноды:

```
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("fb", "http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0"); 

var body = doc.Root.XPathSelectElements("fb:body", namespaceManager).ToList();
```

выглядит страшно, но это из-за того, что Linq to XML предполагает работу с XML как с деревом объектов. Вот более простой вариант без использования XPath:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0";
var body = doc.Root.Elements(ns + "body").ToList();
```

Comment: а в последних двух строках точно не пропущен слеш? либо после 2.0 либо перед body.

Comment: @KoVadim точно. ns - не string. ns + "body" - тоже не string.